# How do I collect all the οbjects created from abstract class in a arraylist

Tags: java, abstract-class

How do I collect all the οbjects created from abstract class in a arraylist?

Here is what i've tried so far :

```
package exercice3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Personne {
    
    protected String nom ;
    protected String prenom ; 
    protected String adresse ;
    protected static int nbPersonnes = 0 ; 
    List<Personne> ListePersonnes = new ArrayList <>();
    
    public Personne(String nom , String prenom , String adresse) {
        
        this.nom= nom ; 
        this.prenom = prenom ; 
        this.adresse = adresse ; 
        nbPersonnes++;
        ListePersonnes.add(nbPersonnes, );
    }
}
```

Comment: each time you will create object a new ListePersonnes will be created for that object. You need to make your List static and call/get it using class name like this, Personne.ListePersonnes;

Comment: I have my own doubts whether your code is even compiling. You are trying to add an `int` to a Collection of type `Personne`

Comment: You can'not instantiate Personne class since it is abstract. Whats why you can put in  ListePersonnes only non-abstract class object wich extends Personne. And whats why ListePersonnes should be static in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public abstract class Personne {
           
    protected String nom ;
    protected String prenom ; 
    protected String adresse ;
    protected static int nbPersonnes = 0 ; 
    static List<Personne> ListePersonnes = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    
    public Personne(String nom , String prenom , String adresse) {
        
        this.nom= nom ; 
        this.prenom = prenom ; 
        this.adresse = adresse ; 
        nbPersonnes++;
        ListePersonnes.add(this);  // <== use 'this' keyword
    
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is better to intialize the list as `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` to ensure thread safety as the list is `static`.